# How to find the package name which has been uninstalled when using Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-package-managers

I have an application which is keeping a log of internally developed applications installed on the device. Upon installation a broadcast receiver for Intent.PACKAGE_ADDED is invoked and records the package name using the following code:

```
public class NewInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        int uid = b.getInt(Intent.EXTRA_UID);
        String[] packages = context.getPackageManager().getPackagesForUid(uid);

        ApplicationService appService = new ApplicationService(context);
        appService.ApplicationInstalled(packages);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is when using a broadcast receiver for Intent.PACKAGE_REMOVED, all reference to the package via the unique Id (UID) comes back with null information (As you would expect, given its already been uninstalled).  I have a temporary solution for the meantime, but its not very elegant, and for the next version I would like to have cleaner code.  An example of how the code should work:

```
public class RemoveApplicationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        int uid = b.getInt(Intent.EXTRA_UID);
        String[] packages = context.getPackageManager().getPackagesForUid(uid);

        ApplicationService appService = new ApplicationService(context);
        appService.ApplicationRemoved(packages);
    }

}
```

So to recap, the question is:

How, after a program has been removed, can I reference the package name in a broadcast receiver for Intent.PACKAGE_REMOVED.

Thanks

Comment: I am also getting null from getPackagesForUid(uid). What i want is to get list of all packages installed for current user. Can any one provide some input?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The package names are in the Intent you got from BroadcasReceiver, use the "getData()" function, there is the ComponentMame of the installed/uninstalled package.

Comment: Worked great... simply used getData().getSchemeSpecificPart().  Thanks

Comment: When I print out intent.toString() I can see the package name, but when I use intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart() I get an empty string.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @gonzobrains You probably didn't set the scheme? In the manifest, it should look like this: `<data android:scheme="package" />`.

Answer (score 0):

When installing the application. `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
`BroadcastReceiver` method `onReceive`

```
val packageManager = context.packageManager
val uId = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_UID, -1)
val packageName = packageManager.getPackagesForUid(uId)?.first() ?: return
```

When uninstalled the application. `ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED` or `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED)

```
val packageName = intent.data?.schemeSpecificPart ?: return
```

Get app name or icon

```
val applicationInfo = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
  packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.of(0))
} else {
  @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
  packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0)
}

val appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo)
val appIcon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo)
```

**Attention**
When installing the application, if use `intent.data?.schemeSpecificPart` not on all devices the correct one is returned package name.