# Callback after my application was installed?

Tags: android, installation

Is there any callback / receiver / anything that gets called once when my application is installed?

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562413/android-how-to-get-the-installed-app-information-using-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 6):

For this, you have to make one application apart from your main application that can keep tracking about the install or uninstalled application from your device.

For this you need to register the Receiver.

```
<receiver android:name=".AppStatusReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

AppStatusReceiver.java

```
public class AppStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Intent: " + intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

Note : *If you are looking this to be manage from your main application callback then it is no possible.*

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for an app to run code when it was installed.

For other apps, you could create a `BroadcastReceiver` for [`ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED), but as the docs explain, this won't work for the app that was newly installed:

> Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.