# How to get app details from receiving intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

My app receives and analyze data from received intent (ACTION.SEND). Intent has many details in extras depending upon the application.

What I want is packageID of application from which my has received the intent?

Is there any standard way to achieve this?

Comment: are you using `IntentSender`?

Comment: No. I have never used it. I am reading directly receiving intent object.

Comment: you could get the package name with a simple method -> `this.getPackageName ()` where `this` is your context

Comment: I think this.getPackageName() will give my own app' package name. Isn't it?

Comment: yes, it will. But which one do you want?

Comment: Go through the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910411/how-to-find-the-package-name-which-has-been-uninstalled-when-using-intent-action

Answer (score 0):

If you need this application details in many activities of your application, you could save them into the `Shared preferences` and use them from all of the activities without passing them each time as extras in an intent. You could do it this way for example:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(preffName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); //preffName is a String variable with the name of your preferences - just use the same string every time 
editor.putString("AppName", "MyApplication");
editor.putInt("PackageID", "MyPackageID");
editor.commit();
```

And then you could get the saved data like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(preffName, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String appName = prefs.getString("AppName", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
String packageID = prefs.getString("PackageID", "No package id is defined."); //"No package id is defined" is the default value
```

Comment: I think you are not getting my question. I want package info of any app who sends Action.SEND intent and My app receive that intent.

Comment: Then maybe this tutorial could be helpful for you http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-receiving-data-from-the-send-intent--mobile-14878

Comment: this what all I have already implemented. Reading action type, reading MIME etc. I am already doing all this and working fine.  It doesn't show how to get packageInfo of send app.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this [How to find Intent source in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789155/how-to-find-intent-source-in-android) it seems impossible or very tricky solution. There is no direct way to achieve this. Ahh Android.